# Keyboard overlaps Custom edit text

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, keyboard

I have a an `EditText` with a `drawable` background (A rectangle shape with corners and a color, nothing fancy)[image]

**Case 1** When the `EditText` gets focus on click, view shifts above but the soft keyboard still partially overlaps it so that the hint is visible properly but the background is trimmed.

**Case 2** (Inside a fragment, coz this issue does not occur in an Activity) If I press next from an edit text above the target `EditText` the background is again trimmed and the keyboard is just touching the bottom of the hint.

I have enclosed it inside a `ScrollView`, tried `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize"` (with different combinations too) but **nothing seems to work**.

Is there a way to `override` the y-axis by which the view is pushed when soft keyboard opens?

Comment: I am facing same problem. Have you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Half of the job is done by `Scrollview` itself,

Try to writing these line in you `onFocusChanged` method of `edittext`

```
editText.requestLayout();
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_UNSPECIFIED);
```

and your .xml would be like -

```
<LinearLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
  android:orientation="vertical" 
  android:layout_width="match_parent" 
  android:layout_height="match_parent" > 

        <ScrollView
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:weightSum="1">

        .... your editetexts here...

        </ScrollView> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

It happened because, when you use custom background, all insets, like padding was dropped. So, just add this param:
`android:paddingVertical="14dp"`

That will resolve your issue.

Comment: Interesting, but unfortunately, the project was scraped many years ago and since I can't test it, I cannot mark this as a correct solution but thank you for your answer.